# Sobreescribir filas con python

Tags: python

Alguien que sepa como????
Comparto con vosotros el codigo *au revoir*.

```
import csv

def leer():
    m1=open("archivo1.csv","rb")
    m1_csv=csv.reader(m1)
    var = ""

    for i,x in enumerate(m1_csv):

        lista0 = x[0:1]
        lista1 = x[1:2]
        header = str1 = ''.join(lista0)
        header1 = header[9:13]
        str1 = ''.join(lista1)
        str1 = str1[1:]
        str2 = str1[0:32]

        listas = []
        listas.append("The next header ")
        listas.append(header1)
        listas.append("")
        if(header1=="goin"):
            listas.remove("")
            listas.remove("goin")
            listas.append("error")    
            listas.append(" the hash is outdate: "+str2)        
        elif(header1=="omin"):
            listas.remove("")
            listas.remove("omin")
            listas.append("error")    
            listas.append(" the hash is outdate: "+str2)            
        elif( str2 == "074e3e3e82db7610dbeafd95c22d20a2"):
            listas.remove("")
            listas.append(" is using for speaking")
            listas.append(" example bla bla bla the packet")
            listas.append(" Incident: you can get powers")

        listo=["OUTGOING HEADERS"]
        listos=["INCOMING HEADERS"]

        m2_c=csv.writer(open("archivo2.csv","a"),lineterminator='\n')
        if(i==0):
            m2_c.writerow(listo)
        if(i==468):
            m2_c.writerow(listos)
        m2_c.writerow(listas)

    m1.close()

#escribir sin espacios
```

Comment: ¿Podías explicar un poco más de qué va el código? No pienso leer el código para averiguar cuál es el problema que quieres resolver.

Comment: No hace falta que lo leas el codigo lo que hace es leer un archivo y entonces creo una lista y luego la escribo en un fichero aparte simplemente pero cuando uso la opcion w me escribe en la misma linea pero si utilizo la opcion a y lineterminator me escribe en diferentes lineas lo que quiero hacer es que me agregue la informacion y sobreescriba cada fila y sino es posible lo que hare sera renombrar el archivo y crear un fichero nuevo asi hago una copia del fichero nuevo

Comment: Perfecto. Sería mejor que este comentario lo añadieras a la pregunta para completarla. Así queda mucho más claro cuál es el problema que tienes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando abres el fichero para escritura, el modo 'a' (*append*) únicamente permite escribir al final del fichero. Para poder *"sobrescribir"* tendrás que añadir al modo el caracter `+`, o sea, `a+`, `a+b` para ficheros binarios, como parece que usas.

En resumen, éstas son las combinaciones:

```
                  | r   r+   w   w+   a   a+
------------------|--------------------------
read              | +   +        +        +
write             |     +    +   +    +   +
create            |          +   +    +   +
truncate          |          +   +
position at start | +   +    +   +
position at end   |                   +   +
```

Para moverte por el fichero, emplea el método [`seek`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek), aunque sería mucho mejor que procesaras todo en memoria y guardar a fichero al final del proceso.